# Enterprise Collection Features (Specifically Infopath Forms) will not activate

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, feature-activation

I am trying to implement the **Enterprise Site Collection feature** set on my school's SharePoint 2013 Enterprise implementation, but when I go into `Site Settings -> Site Collection Features` and  activate "Sharepoint Server Enterprise Site Collection Features" I receive the following error:

> The field with Id {d4a6af1d-c6d7-4045-8def-cefa25b9ec31} defined in feature {0c8a9a47-22a9-4798-82f1-00e62a96006e} was found in the current site collection or in a subsite.

Could someone walk me through a solution for this? Note that I am not a SharePoint developer, nor administrator but have been given agency to implement this to utilize InfoPath for form deployment at our Support Center.

When the correlation ID is run I got the following relevant errors:

> [Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 10/05/2015 14:12:48.24, Original Level: Verbose] Skip initializating feature definition reservse lookup table and use delayed initialization.

and

> SPException thrown: Message: The field with Id {d4a6af1d-c6d7-4045-8def-cefa25b9ec31} defined in feature {0c8a9a47-22a9-4798-82f1-00e62a96006e} was found in the current site collection or in a subsite.. Stack:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.ThrowSPExceptionWithTraceTag(UInt32 tagId, ULSCat traceCategory, String resourceId, Object[] resourceArgs)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPElementDefinitionCollection.ProvisionFieldsAndContentTypes(SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, SPSite site, SPWeb web, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean fForce)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPElementDefinitionCollection.ProvisionElements(SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, SPWebApplication webapp, SPSite site, SPWeb web, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean fForce)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.Activate(SPSite siteParent, SPWeb webParent, SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean fForce)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.AddInternal(SPFeatureDefinition featdef, Version version, SPFeaturePropertyCollection properties, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean force, Boolean fMarkOnly)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.CheckSameScopeDependency(SPFeatureDefinition featdefDependant, SPFeatureDependency featdep, SPFeatureDefinition featdefDependency, Boolean fActivateHidden, Boolean fUpgrade, Boolean fForce, Boolean fMarkOnly)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.CheckFeatureDependency(SPFeatureDefinition featdefDependant, SPFeatureDependency featdep, Boolean fActivateHidden, Boolean fUpgrade, Boolean fForce, Boolean fMarkOnly, FailureReason& errType)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.CheckFeatureDependencies(SPFeatureDefinition featdef, Boolean fActivateHidden, Boolean fUpgrade, Boolean fForce, Boolean fThrowError, Boolean fMarkOnly, List`1& missingFeatures)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.AddInternal(SPFeatureDefinition featdef, Version version, SPFeaturePropertyCollection properties, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean force, Boolean fMarkOnly)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.AddInternalWithName(Guid featureId, Int32 compatibilityLevel, String featureName, Version version, SPFeaturePropertyCollection properties, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean force, Boolean fMarkOnly, Boolean fIgnoreMissing, SPFeatureDefinitionScope featdefScope)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.FeatureActivator.ActivateFeature(Guid featid, Int32 compatibilityLevel, SPFeatureDefinitionScope featdefScope)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.FeatureActivatorItem.ToggleFeatureActivation()     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)     at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)     at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There are reserved fields that the Enterprise Feature uses, and it looks like there is a custom solution, site template, list template, list, or other feature that may be using. According to that ID (0c8a9a47-22a9-4798-82f1-00e62a96006e), the fields is called "Priority". This column may need to be deleted all together.

See more here: https://sharepointmalarkey.wordpress.com/2010/10/12/sharepoint-internal-field-names-sharepoint-2010/

The feature that is trying to create that field is called DocumentRoutingResources: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mcsnoiwb/archive/2010/01/07/features-and-their-guid-s-in-sp2010.aspx